# Javascript Object sync with XML

Tags: javascript

I have a web app which will do the majority of its work in browser javascript. When the app loads I need to deserialze an XML document and convert the xml elements into javascript objects. I need to then poll this XML document at regular intervals to keep my objects up to date.

My question is...is there a framework I could use to help me here? I'd like to be able to do this intelligently, like not have to ditch all the objects I have in memory each time I poll the XML file. Only get the new ones...or changed ones etc. Thanks.

Something like Breeze? http://www.breezejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

A MVC style Javascript Framework would be a possibility.

Example: http://javascriptmvc.com/

Comment: Thanks, for the input but I don't think an MVC is specific enough for the problem I'm trying to solve.